# Can contemporary batteries report on their health status?

Tags: windows, laptop, battery, battery-life

The battery on my laptop is weak and I have a bunch of spare ones I could reuse. One problem, though, is to quickly estimate which ones are "better" than the others.

Windows (7, 8, 10) have the `powercfg /batteryreport` command which outputs several information about the battery - but merely statistical ones.

**I would be interested in understanding if there is a measure of wear built into contemporary batteries** - which they can report (something similar to [S.M.A.R.T.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) for hard drives)

The closest I got to was, in the output of `powercfg /batteryreport`

```
DESIGN CAPACITY mWh
FULL CHARGE CAPACITY    mWh
CYCLE COUNT -
```

which in my case is empty. The battery is 3 years old so it should have some information - maybe the command did not reach to the right place.

If it makes a difference, this is on a Lenovo W530.